# Grabbing the right name from an Enum in C# using a value

Tags: c#, enums

I have the following enumerator.

```
public enum Fruits
    {
        Banana = 1,
        Apple = 2,
        Blueberry = 3,
        Orange = 4
    }
```

And what I'd like to do is something like the following

```
static void FruitType(int Type)
    {
        string MyType = Enum.GetName(Fruits, Type);
    }
```

Basically I want the string MyType to populate with the name corresponding to the integer I input. So if I enter 1, MyType should have a value of Banana.

Eg. FruitType(1) --> MyType = Banana

Comment: On of the reasons this is not normally done is that the strings obtained this way are hard to localize. Just an fyi. I'll have an answer in a minute after I dig up some old code that demonstrates this.

Comment: Also, a better FruitType function design would return a string

Comment: Okay, others beat me to it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first parameter of [GetName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx) requires the type.

```
static void FruitType(int Type)
{
   string MyType = Enum.GetName(typeof(Fruits), Type);
}
```

If you're not planning on doing anything else in the method, you can return the string like this

```
static string FruitType(int Type)
{
   return Enum.GetName(typeof(Fruits), Type);
}

string fruit = FruitType(100);
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(fruit))
   Console.WriteLine(fruit); 
else
   Console.WriteLine("Fruit doesn't exist");
```

Comment: `Convert.ToString` doesn't ensure null.

Comment: If you want to avoid null you could do `Enum.GetName(typeof(Fruits), Type) ?? string.Empty`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Sorry, I'm not following. I said it ensures that a NullReferenceException isn't thrown, not that it ensures null. `Enum.GetName` returns null if the enum value can't be found. If you call `ToString` on that, it will throw an exception. By using `Convert.ToString` instead, it will return null.

Comment: Without `Convert.ToString` will a `NullReferenceException` be thrown?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Ah right, I'm with you now, the conversion call is unnecessary.

Comment: so is the method okay now?

Comment: @user2094139 - Yup. It was fine before, it just had an extra call that wasn't necessary (forgot a string was being returned anyway from the `GetName` call).

Answer (score 2):

Basically I want the string MyType to populate with the name corresponding to the integer I input.

```
string str = ((Fruits)1).ToString();
```

You can modify your method like:

```
static string FruitType(int Type)
{
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Fruits), Type))
    {

        return ((Fruits)Type).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "Not defined"; 
    }
}
```

The use it like

```
string str = FruitType(2);
```